# Using Reveal.js as Asciidoctor backen when using Rake

Tags: ruby, rake, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-revealjs

I would like to create some slides with the help of [Asciidoctor Reveal.js](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctor-revealjs/) an thought it would be adequate to build my slides with Rake. But I am to s****d to set Reveal.js as backend for Asciidoctor.

```
require 'asciidoctor'

task default: %w[html5]

MASTER_FILENAME='slides.adoc'
OUTPUT_FILENAME='index.html'

task :html5 do
  puts "Source is #{MASTER_FILENAME}"

  begin
    Asciidoctor.convert_file MASTER_FILENAME,
                             safe: :safe,
                             to_file: OUTPUT_FILENAME
                             backend: 'revealjs'

    puts "\t#{OUTPUT_FILENAME} created"
  rescue StandardError => e
    puts "\t" +  e.message
  end
end
```

Any suggestion how to enable Reveal.js as backend?

Comment: are you sure this is even supported? see https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/wiki/APIs-for-Backend-Templates but also maybe see https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-backends

Comment: I don't know. The page you mention hasn't been updated since 28th of Jun 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Reveal.js is, by itself, not a backend for Asciidoctor.

`asciidoctor-reveal.js` is a converter that orchestrates the conversion of Asciidoctor source files into HTML that uses reveal.js. By using asciidoctor.js, `asciidoctor-reveal.js` can be registered at runtime as an asciidoctor.js backend (it has no affect on the Ruby-based `asciidoctor` command-line tool).

You need to adjust your rake processing to follow the instructions here: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctor-revealjs/#node-javascript-setup